# Wrong hostname with jdbc (replace it automatically)

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, hostname

I have a problem when I try to connect to my DB : I think maybe my mysql-connector changes the database's URL automatically, and I don't know how to fix it... 
But It might be another problem, in fact I don't really know what it is.

Here is my code :

```
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String url_db = "jdbc:mysql://mysqldev.fundp.ac.be:3306/neptun";
private static String login = "";
private static String pwd = "";
private static RepositoryParams rep = new RepositoryParams();
private static String path = rep.getPath() ;
private static boolean canConnect = true;
private static Connection connect;
private static FileUtils fU = new FileUtils();
    private ConnectToDb() {
    boolean driverOk = false;
    setParamsToConnect();
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        driverOk = true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : Unable to load the Oracle driver:");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (driverOk) {
        try {
            if (canConnect) {
                System.out.println("Oracle drivers load successfully");
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url_db, login, pwd);
            } 

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            printSQLException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Oracle drivers load successfully
SQLException > SQLState: 28000
SQLException > Message :Access denied for user 'neptun'@'anthony-morre.bump.fundp.ac.be' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: This error shows that you need privilege to access D.B from your machine with this username and password. Now it have no privilege to connect D.B with this username and password.

Comment: @pikrut note the JDBC URL: the server name is *mysqldev.fundp.ac.be* but the stacktrace shows *anthony-morre.bump.fundp.ac.be*.

Comment: Looks like you're not executing the code you're looking at. Try to clean your environment, rebuild and relaunch your application.

Comment: The url should be "jdbc:mysql://hostAddress:port/dBName" this means the D.B name should be at last. for example if D.B in localhost and port is 3306 D.B name is myDB then "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB" Also grant privilage for the D.B with the username and password that you giving.

Comment: Unfortunatlly I am executing this code, I've rebuilt the project but it doesn't work.
The problem is that the URL is right (It works with another project) but here I don't know why the program is using the subnetwork on wich I am, and not the url of de database